# WCF service failing The message could not be dispatched because the service at the endpoint address is unavailable for the protocol of the address

Tags: wcf, connectivity

The service is hosted in IIS it works fine but once a week it gives this issue. I checked the code all service calls from client are closed. Also we call these services from Biztalk daily which is net.tcp configured through WCF adapters.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open a command prompt.
2. Navigate to c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework64\v4.0.30319.
3. Register the service model using the command "ServiceModelReg.exe -r".

You can also try to restart the Net.Tcp listener adapter service. This has a similar problem, you can refer to [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393210/wcf-the-message-could-not-be-dispatched-because-the-service-at-the-endpoint-ad).